# Sagemaker Endpoint returns error when trying to make a prediction in the Sagemaker Notebook Instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I've deployed an inference pipeline endpoint on sagemaker, but now when I try to make a prediction call but I get an error message and to the best of my knowledge I am following the examples shown here:
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_inference_pipeline/Inference%20Pipeline%20with%20Scikit-learn%20and%20Linear%20Learner.ipynb

The code to make an endpoint call is here:

```
from sagemaker.predictor import json_serializer, csv_serializer, json_deserializer, RealTimePredictor
from sagemaker.content_types import CONTENT_TYPE_CSV, CONTENT_TYPE_JSON

predictor = RealTimePredictor(
    endpoint='Boston-inf-pipeline-July09-endpoint',
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    serializer=csv_serializer,
    content_type=CONTENT_TYPE_CSV,
    accept=CONTENT_TYPE_CSV)


from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import Binarizer, StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

column_names = ['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT', 'MEDV']

dff = pd.read_csv('housing.csv',delimiter=r"\s+", names=column_names)

dff.drop('MEDV',axis=1,inplace=True)

 
#String
x = '0.00632,18.0,2.31,0,0.538,6.575,65.2,4.09,1,296.0,15.3,396.9,4.98'

#DataFrame
y= dff.head(1)

#Array
z = np.array([0.00632,18.0,2.31,0,0.538,6.575,65.2,4.09,1,296.0,15.3,396.9,4.98])

print(predictor.predict(x))**strong text**
```

and here is the error message:

[image]

and here is what is says on Cloud Watch

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your SageMaker endpoint raised a `ValueError` in the screenshot of the cloudwatch logs:

```
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s)...
```

It seems as though the model you've deployed is expecting an input of a different shape, as described in [Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 40)) while a minimum of 1 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632550/found-array-with-0-samples-shape-0-40-while-a-minimum-of-1-is-required).

The sagemaker endpoint is claiming the "shape" of the numpy input value you're passing is `(0, 13)`, and is most likely expecting `(1, 13)`. From your client script, it looks as though you're passing an array of shape `(13,)` and it eventually get's interpreted as `(0, 13)` in the SageMaker container.

Can you try adding another dimension to your input to make the input shape `(1, 13)` in your clientside script?

```
z = np.array([[0.00632,18.0,2.31,0,0.538,6.575,65.2,4.09,1,296.0,15.3,396.9,4.98]])
```

P.S.: I'm working on a *faster*, *cheaper*, and *easy-to-use* platform for deploying `sklearn` models at https://modelzoo.dev. You might be a good match for our private beta program -- reach out at `contact@modelzoo.dev` and I can help you get set up.

Comment: While adding another dimension was not the ultimate fix, following your observation on the shape of the input I made tweaks to the code and now its fix and the error is gone! Downside is now I'm getting a new error :(